# C#: Background color problem

Tags: c#, colors, background

I am having trouble with background colors in C#. For some reason they are simply not working. Specifically on the System.Windows.Forms.Panel control. Setting the BackColor property does nothing. All I have is gray and all the efforts I have made will not change it. Is there something that could be overriding this? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: No its definitely enabled. I've even explicitly set enabled to true with no change.

Comment: Is this programmatic or through the designer?

Comment: Ive done it both ways and still no result.

Comment: Is this a derived panel?  Any custom painting logic for the Form in which the panel derives?  Any non-default property settings on the panel in either the Appearance or the Design categories in the PropertyGrid?

Comment: Are you extending the AeroGlassProvider onto your form?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the Panel Control the same color as the Form's background color, then you can use this:

```
myPanel.Parent = this;
```

... I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had instances where controls must have both the foreground and background colors specified, you might want to try setting the foreground color explicitly as well, to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your control is being repainted without your knowledge.

To try to rule this out, I would add a Form Load event, and force the following properties:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon; // or any other color
   this.panel1.Visible = true
}
```

And on the designer, I would bring the control to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with two overlayed panels in one form.  I inadvertently had one panel as a child of the other main when I created them in Design View.