# Visual Studio C# Windows Forms... changing button color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form (see screenshot):

[image: default form look]

As you can see, its a pretty basic form, with a save button. I have programmed it so that if any of the text fields get changed, the "SAVE" button changes color so that its obvious that I haven't clicked save and don't forget to. Unfortunately, simply changing the BackColor of the button to red isn't enough, because its UGLY as sin.

[image: ugly backcolor unsaved]

What can I do to change the color of the button to red, but not as ugly. As you can see, the "BackColor" doesn't change the entire button, just the inner piece. The border is still the same old fashioned transparent grey.

Comment: Maybe the forecolor (instead of the backcolor) would be enough?

Comment: The simplest way would be to convert the application to WPF you would have far greater control.  Since that is a good amount of work you will have to inherit the button control, and change how the button is draw, if changing the value **BackColor** doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I'd personally keep the save button disabled until something had changed. Enabled on changed details, then disable it again on click. Just another alternative :)

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think the better advice that can be given to the OP is "rewrite entirely your application"

Comment: @ken2k- He doesn't have to "rewrite" the entire application. All he has to do is use a Window class instead of a Win32 class.  If you have a better solution then provide one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little bit of a `LinearGradientBrush` can go a long way to soften the harshness of a pure red button.

```
button1.ForeColor = Color.White;

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(button1.Width, button1.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
  using (LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(
                                      r,
                                      Color.Red,
                                      Color.DarkRed,
                                      LinearGradientMode.Vertical)) {
      g.FillRectangle(br, r);
    }
  }
```

then you can just assign the image to the button's `BackgroundImage` property:

```
  button1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Result:

[image]

Note: Assigning a background image will lose the mouse hover coloring of the button.

Comment: I wonder if you could use transparency on the BackgroundImage to make it blend with the original button.

Comment: How would I then remove the background image?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Just a simple `button1.BackgroundImage = null;` would work.

Comment: @LarsTech can I remove the border from the button

Comment: @madan You can try using the paint event of the button.  You probably will have to reimplement the mouse hover and mouse down look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to add an [Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) (e.g. exclamation mark) to the button instead to inform the user that the changes haven't been saved yet.

Comment: Another solution would be to have automatic saves.  One could also use Ribbon or ToolStrip.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials online on how to create nice buttons with c#. For example this one allows you to create Vista like buttons. Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19318/Vista-Style-Button-in-C

For basic colors visit this SO question:

[C#: Changing Button BackColor has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127946/c-changing-button-backcolor-has-no-effect)

Comment: The tutorial has since been taken down: `"We're sorry, but the article you are trying to view was deleted at 18 May 2013."`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one of the button's properties, "FlatStyle". By default, it is standard. But if you switch it to "Popup", your background color will be extended to the area of the button. You can compare the followings:

[left-standard, right-popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WngEG.png)

Comment: welcome to SO! it's discouraged to resurrect old questions (2012!), especially those that have accepted answers.

Comment: thanks this helped me to finally remove those ugly borders!

Answer (score -1):

This won't work in WinForms, but you might want to switch over to WPF.
It's much more convenient because you can configure EVERYTHING. (Even the color of a progressbar)

Edit: The OP doesn't have to entirely rewrite his application.
He just needs to redo the layout of it, the code can be C&P'd over to the new WPF project, fyi

Edit²: You don't even need to use code to change the color of a WPF button, you can just define a red overlay with 30% opacity in the XAML file. It's that easy, really.

Comment: I guess those downvotes came from people who never heard about WPF.

Comment: No, WPF is really a great technology. But as OP is using Winforms, the "rewrite all your application, move to WPF" answer is a really bad answer.

Comment: See the edit on the answer for my answer to that. ;) Edit: @noah1989 It is, because it shows the OP the limits of the old WinForms platform and the advantages of WPF. I only started programming with WPF a month ago, and it's already paying off.

Comment: @ken2k - This is a perfectly valid answer to the question that was asked.  The author wanted to know how to make the button change color and not look "ugly" which only leaves him two options.  Use WPF which allows far greater control over the controls or to write his own button control.

Comment: If the view and model has not been split in a good way, then converting to WPF can still be a lot of work.

Comment: @Ramhound "This won't work, move to WPF" is not an acceptable answer for me. There are plenty of examples about how designing winforms controls (especially buttons) on the web. WPF is not the same technology at all. If you want to write clean WPF, you'll have to learn MVVM, commanding, XAML...etc. which require a large amount of work. On top of that, WPF requires at least .net 3.0, so you can't just say "move to WPF".

Comment: That might be a problem, I agree. But since the OP didn't say anything about his code, I assumed he did split it in a good way. Edit: What's bad about learning new, helpful stuff or .NET 3.0?

Comment: also, with Windows 8 and Metro -- WPF will be obsolete again... not?

Comment: WPF will be obsolete? Your comment is the only thing that's obsolete here. Win 8 will continue to support WPF and WinForms just like its precedessors.

Comment: Well.. for desktops -- yes, but not for tablets and mobile devices. Although migrating might be much easier, because you can use XAML with Metro Style Apps (WinRT)

Comment: WPF was MADE for tablets and that sort of devices. You might wanna look into all the touchscreen features of WPF.

Comment: @PeterW. yeah, but I can't see any WPF here: [APIs for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211369)

Comment: @noah1989 Obviously, the OP is not building a Metro style application, so both Winforms and WPF are supported.

Comment: @noah1989 That's because you linked to the APIs for Metro style apps. I can't find anything about WPF in the iPhone's API docs either.

Comment: @ken2k my point here was that if one was migrating to WPF just because it's a newer technology he might just use WinRT instead. But imo the OP should just stick with WinForms.

Comment: also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697414/winrt-and-wpf-in-windows-8

Comment: @noah1989 WinRT is not backwards compabible, so WPF would be the better choice here. Though, if the OP was building a "pure" Metro app, WinRT would be indeed the right choice.

Comment: If he were to support Windows 98, WinForms (on .NET 2.0) would be the only choice ;-)

Comment: Thank God no one tries to support that anymore, right? ...right?