# Changing buttons' and pictureboxes' BackColor on all forms

Tags: c#, button, picturebox, backcolor

In my application I have got an option to customise display a bit. Basically, now it is about changing buttons' and pictureboxes' images, changing form icons etc. As you can see in the code I provided bellow. So, in this case, I have done this by simply loading a bunch of resources (images) and then when I change theme:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Purple")
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
    {
        form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
    }

    Main f1 = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
    Settings f2 = (Settings)Application.OpenForms["Settings"];

    f1.btn_Exit.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_purple;
    f2.btn_SaveSettings.Image = Properties.Resources.SaveSettings_purple;

    f1.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Preview_purple;
}
```

This dramatically increases the size of the application, so I came up with changing BackColor instead of loading another images. I have tried to solve this in the following way:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Purple")
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
    {
        form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
    }

    Main f1 = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
    Settings f2 = (Settings)Application.OpenForms["Settings"];

    f1.btn_Exit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(164, 57, 226);
    f2.btn_SaveSettings.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(164, 57, 226);

    f2.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(164, 57, 226);
}
```

So, form icon should be changed on all running forms and I have managed to successfully do so, but when it comes to buttons and pictureboxes, I am not seeing any results, that is buttons and pictureboxes are simply not changing. Besides form icons, I should change `btn_Exit` located on the `Main` form, `btn_SaveSettings` located on the `Settings` form, and `pictureBox1` located on the `Settings` form as well.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is `btn_Exit` ? A property of `Main` returning what? And idea with Themeing is a bit wrong, imagine you have 100 forms and 10 buttons on each.. there should be rather some interface or component similar to `ToolTip` attaching property `Themeable=true` and registering control, so you just go through all registered controls in single loop and changing their properties at once.

Comment: btn_Exit is a button located on form named Main. I don't know how to answer this question more precisely. Anyway, I can see where are you coming from and I know that this is not the best solution, but it works for me. Do you have any suggestions how can I have desired results in my case?

Comment: I'll try to guess, what pictures are covering the whole area of buttons or pictureBoxes, so you don't see result of changing `BackColor`.

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127946/c-changing-button-backcolor-has-no-effect?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If it was me doing it I would make an interface. This interface would have a reference to the correct picture/icon/color for your different controls. The Settings for you application would hold an instance of the correct theme. Each form I would OnLoad update all the necessary items and call it a day. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it would make it easy and quick when you go to add more themes.

This is what I was thinking about. I hope this clears up my approach.

```
public class Settings
{
    public static ITheme Theme {get {return theme;}{set theme = value}}

    theme = new DefaultTheme();
}
public interface ITheme
{
    public Color BackgroundColor {get;}
    public Color ButtonBackgroundColor { get;}

    //... etc
}
public class DefaultTheme : ITheme
{
    public Color BackgroundColor {get{ return Color.White;}}
    public Color ButtonBackgroundColor { get { return Color.Gray;}}

}
```

from here you have 2 approaches. Both require you to put a Event "OnLoad" If you have 1 or 2 forms maybe put this code each Form (not recommended) or you could use an extension like method.

here is first approach. put the code directly in each frame.

```
public class SaveFrame : Frame
{
    public SaveFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    public Form_OnLoad()
    {
        var theme = Settings.Theme;

        this.Background = theme.BackgroundColor;
        foreach(Button b in this.Controls)
        {
            if(b != null)
                b.Background = theme.ButtonBackgroundColor;
        }
    }

}
```

or create an extension method. and put it in the OnLoad

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateTheme(this Form form, ITheme theme)
    {
        form.Background = theme.BackgroundColor;
        foreach(Button b in form.Controls)
        {
            if(b != null)
                b.Background = theme.ButtonBackgroundColor;
        }

    }
}
public class SaveFrame : Form
{
    public SaveFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    public Form_OnLoad()
    {
        this.UpdateTheme(Settings.Theme);
    }
}
public class MainFrame :Form
{
    public MainFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    public Form_OnLoad()
    {
        this.UpdateTheme(Settings.Theme);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this is not the best solution, but it works for me. Do you know how can I solve the problem in my case?

Comment: see edit. I hope this clarifies things. I didn't check my work so be careful about copy and pasting.